# Event handler function to wxButton with Bind() - wxWidgets 3.0

Tags: c++, events, button, event-handling, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a simple, basic application to start off with wxWidgets. I can already set up a frame and put menu, menu items and buttons on it and it all displays properly.

However I have troubles using Bind() to attach an event handler to the button. To strip the code a bit, I have this :

```
class MainFrameFunctions
{
public:
void buttonOneClicked(wxCommandEvent & event);
};

void MainFrameFunctions::buttonOneClicked(wxCommandEvent & event)
{
// do something
}

MainFrame::MainFrame(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint& , const wxSize& , long style, const wxString& ) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, size1)
{
wxButton * buttonOne = new wxButton( panelOne, buttonOneID, wxT("Show Box"), wxPoint(70,50), wxSize(200,40) );
}
```

So I wonder, how do I make an event handler with Bind(), to connect the handler function "buttonOneClicked" to buttonOne ? And also where in code do I put the Bind() line ?

**EDIT**

After recommendation by VZ. I have made some edits to the program, so that the main components now look like this :

```
class MainFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
MainFrame(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint  

    &pos=wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize &size=wxDefaultSize, long style=wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, const wxString &name=wxFrameNameStr);

void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
bool ButtonOneClicked(wxCommandEvent & event);
wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};


class CreateNewFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
CreateNewFrame(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint& , const wxSize&, long style);
void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};


MainFrame::MainFrame(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint& , const wxSize& , long style, const wxString& )
: wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, size1)
{
 wxButton * buttonOne = new wxButton( panelOne, buttonOneID, wxT("Button One"), wxPoint(70,50), wxSize(200,40), 0, wxDefaultValidator, "PP" );

 // while we are at it, what is the " wxDefaultValidator, "PP" " part about ? I just copied it from an example

 buttonOne->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrame::ButtonOneClicked, this);
}


bool MainFrame::ButtonOneClicked(wxCommandEvent & event)
{
CreateNewFrame* NewFrame = new CreateNewFrame(this, NewFrameID, "Button One Clicked", position2, size2);
NewFrame->Show( true );

return true;
}
```

The problem now is, that I get this error message from CodeBlocks 13.12 :

```
no matching function for call to 'wxButton::Bind(const wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>&, bool (MainFrame::*)(wxCommandEvent&), MainFrame* const)'|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Bind()` the event handler as soon as you want your app to start processing the intended events.
Many times this is done after building the UI, so in your case at the end of `MainFrame()` constructor should be fine.

You can find examples of using `Bind()` in the samples, just like many other wxWidgets features; see `events` sample.
For your case you can do

```
buttonOne->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrameFunctions::buttonOneClicked, aMainFrameFunctionsPointer);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for pointing me at the proper example, I appreciate it. I put the Bind() at the end of MainFrame constructor, and I get an error  "" cannot convert 'MainFrame*' to 'MainFrameFunctions*' in initialization| "" . Do you have any idea maybe how to solve it ? I use CodeBlocks 13.12. Thank you.

Comment: You need to have a pointer to the class whose method you want to bind as a handler, i.e. `MainFrameFunctions` and not `this` which is presumably of the type `MainFrame`. Of course, this assumes that you _intentionally_ want to separate the handlers in a separate class (why?).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I just didn't notice the use of two different classes there. I've updated the suggestion.

Comment: It was my belief that it would make code look more handy and easier for me to read. But after your comment I see it may not be so. I am a beginner though and I lack good programming practices, so I often still get lost when it comes to arranging pieces to make it readable. Thank you both, I understand it now.

Comment: @catalin - I did correct my code so it's like VZ. recommends. That means handler function is now inside Main Frame class. Bind function is now ""buttonOne->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrame::buttonOneClicked, this);""  . 
But I get this error ""no matching function for call to 'wxButton::Bind(const wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>&, bool (MainFrame::*)(wxCommandEvent&), MainFrame* const)'|"" .
Can you make anything out of this ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you change `buttonOneClicked()` to return bool?

Comment: @catalin - I did. Please see my edited question now, I have added part of the new code, which I hope can help solve the mistery. Thank you.

Comment: Change it back to `void`. That `Bind()` form only accepts `void` functions.

Comment: @catalin - Brilliant, that was it. Biggest thanks =))